# Client-side searching in checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help.. for now I'm trying to create a client search but I don't know how to compare values from input text to checkboxes.

***[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FbDvc/1/)***

Example:

```
jQuery("#searchBox").on("keyup paste", function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var rows = jQuery(".sp_country");
        rows.hide();
        if(value === '') {
            rows.show();
            return false;
        } 
   //need something here to compare values on checkboxes and show does checkedbox who match
});
```

Here is my check box located

```
<span class="sp_country">
    <input class="cp_country" style="cursor:pointer; display:none;" type="checkbox" name="country" value="Afghanistan">&nbsp;Afghanistan    
</span>
```

Comment: Where is your checkboxes?

Comment: it was hidden..when you click the span it will be set to check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` method:

```
rows.filter(function() {
   return $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
}).show();
```

Or in case that you want to compare the input with value of checkboxes:

```
rows.filter(function(){
   return this.children[0].value.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
}).show();
```

You can can also use the jQuery's `.find()` method for selecting the input descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("cp_country").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==("#searchBox").val()){
        $(this).parent(".sp_country").show();
    }
});
```

Whole idea is:

```
 iterate through each of the checkbox value
 if the value matches with search box value then
   show the parent span element
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#searchBox").on("keyup paste", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var rows = $(".cp_country");
        rows.hide();
        if(value === '') {
            rows.show();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            rows.each(function(){
               if($(this).val().toUpperCase().indexOf(value) != -1){
                  $(this).show();
               }
               else{ $(this).hide();}
            });

        }
});
```